# How do I save and reference user input c# (ToDo Console app)

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and as my first "program", I want to build a ToDo-list app that runs in console.

I've laid down the basic frame of the program, but I do not seem to find how to save user data outside of the main code and so that it can be referenced again in the next session.

I do not want to save the tasks as variables temporarily.

My idea how my app would work is that if I open the program and I have the choice to either  write/add a task or read the tasks.

If I write a new task the console should display the updated ToDo list with the newest task in addition to tasks i added in past sessions.

Right now I don't plan to add a "delete task" button, maybe after I understand how to solve the first problem. I am using VisualStudio for mac if that is relevant.

Comment: What you are looking for is called **persistent storage** of user data. The problem is that there is a *huge* amount of possibilities, so it's hard to give a single answer here. The two most common solutions are (a) to use a file on disk or (b) to use a database. For (a), you can either invent your own file format or use an existing serialization library. For (b), you can either use a full-blown database system or include a light-weight database (e.g. SQLite) with your application.

Comment: This is an opinion based question. For a starter I would go for the file solution. It is going to be easier to develop and debug in case of trouble. Good luck fellow :)

Comment: @Heinzi i thought of something like a .txt file on a disk, maybe even the same folder the program is in. SQL would be too much in this case, I think.

Comment: @aloisdg thanks, I also think that the file solution fits me more. Is there any kind of documentation around it? I do not seem to find any examples

Comment: Many of the examples online are outdated and more complex than necessary. If you store your TODOs as a list of strings, `File.ReadAllLines` (on program start) and `File.WriteAllLines` (on program termination) should be all you need to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store Data in a File

```
using System.IO;

string pathToFile = "myTodoList.txt";
string[] lines = new string[]{"task1","task2","task3");

File.WriteAllLine(pathToFile,lines);
```

in the txt you will find:

```
task1 
task2 
task3
```

and reading them:

```
using System.IO;

string pathToFile = "myTodoList.txt";
string[] lines = File.readAllLines(pathToFile);

foreach(string line in lines)
{
     Console.ReadLine(line);
}
```

Comment: okay so storing data WORKS. Thanks. But i do not seem to being able to display the lines on the console. How would i achieve that?

Comment: okay so i seemed to find a fix to this. This is the direction i wanted to head into.
if i want to display the files in the console i have to write

using System.IO;
using System;

string pathToFile = "myTodoList.txt";
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(pathToFile);
foreach (string s in lines)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways this can be done.

One of the easiest and most commonly used is with JSON.

Here is a complete program I wrote so that you can experiment with.

```
public class TodoItem
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DueOn { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{this.Description}";
    }
}

internal static class Program
{
    static private readonly string _saveFileName = "todo.json";
    static void Main()
    {
        {
            // An example list containing 2 items
            List<TodoItem> items = new List<TodoItem> {
                new TodoItem { Description = "Feed the dog" },
                new TodoItem { Description = "Buy groceries", DueOn = new DateTime(2021, 9, 30, 16, 0, 0) }
            };
            // Serialize it to JSON
            string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(items, new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true });

            // Save it to a file
            File.WriteAllText(_saveFileName, json);
        }

        // Now we'll load the list back from the file
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText(_saveFileName);

            List<TodoItem> items = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<TodoItem>>(json);

            // Check whether the list has loaded correctly
            foreach (var todo in items)
                Console.WriteLine(todo);
        }

    }
```

---

Program output:

> Feed the dog
> Buy groceries

---

`todo.json` file contents:

```
[
  {
    "Description": "Feed the dog",
    "DueOn": null
  },
  {
    "Description": "Buy groceries",
    "DueOn": "2021-09-30T16:00:00"
  }
]
```

Comment: im really sorry but i dont think i can use this. On the one hand i tried running it and it doesnt work (probably my fault) and also i dont understand a lot of it so i dont know if it works out for me.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? What is not working as expected?

Which part(s) do you not understand?

Comment: it works. I never heared of json but it works. Magic. Thanks a lot. Im going to try to understand it now and hopefully learn a lot.

Comment: @Rarowcun: you are welcome. JSON is the most used generic universal format to save data in. Technically javascript, it's now used by virtually any programming language on any platform. Here is a link to get you started: https://www.infoworld.com/article/3222851/what-is-json-a-better-format-for-data-exchange.html